# MySQL output to PHP page showing a backslash

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that asks for a name.  The php to process it is:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['name']));
```

When someone inserts a name with an apostrophe e.g. Dan O'Shea it shows up in the mysql database fine, but on the webpage it's output shows up as Dan O\Shea.

How do I get rid of the \ backslash and show the ' apostrophe on the webpage? Can I use str_replace('/','', $string) with mysqli_real_escape_string, and if so how?

Thanks for any help,

Andy ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have `gpc_magic_quotes` turned on.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: Thanks Andy.  The problem is not on my localhost - it works fine there.  The problem seems to arise only when I put the code up on a free hosting provider.  Eventually I will go with paid hosting once the site is complete, I am just testing and found this problem. Is this common? Thanks again Andy ;-)

Comment: I don't know how common things may be.  I only work with servers that I admin directly.

Answer (score 1):

use `stripslashes()` to remove extra backslashes.

Comment: Thanks joaofgf, is that with or without the mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @AndyR Use it when you're showing the data in the page. `stripslashes($row['name']);`

Comment: Hi Zerquix18 and joaofgf, when using the localhost I don't have the problem, it's only on a free hosting account that it occurs. So are they being extra cautious or what?

Comment: your hosting provider has `gpc_magic_quotes` enabled and your local server doesn't.